# Why is JTextArea breaking my tab order?

Tags: java, jtextarea, windowbuilder, tab-ordering, tabstop

Why is the JTextArea control ignoring/breaking my tab order?
[Here you can see the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmhwO.png)

The shown tab order property is from the java.awt.Container --> getContentPane() from the JFrame.

I use the eclipse WindowBuilder PlugIn .